# Replace line breaks in a STL string

Tags: c++, stl

How can I replace `\r\n` in an `std::string`?

Comment: Um. What do you want to replace them with? And, maybe a little context would help, no?

Comment: As @dmckee---ex-moderatorkitten says: the code can be a lot simpler, if you only intend to replace it with a string of length less than or equal to the original.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this :

```
while ( str.find ("\r\n") != string::npos )
{
    str.erase ( str.find ("\r\n"), 2 );
}
```

more efficient form is :

```
string::size_type pos = 0; // Must initialize
while ( ( pos = str.find ("\r\n",pos) ) != string::npos )
{
    str.erase ( pos, 2 );
}
```

Comment: Don't run the find twice! Store the position found in the conditional and use it in the body: while (size_type pos = str.find(...)) { str.manipulate(pos,...); };

Comment: Hmmm...that still leaves something to be desired. Each iteration of the loop rescans the bit declared safe by the last pass. Define pos outside the loop and make it persistant: size_type pos = 0; while (pos = str.find("..",pos) )...

Comment: This is an erasure and not a replacement - the question asked was how to replace "\r\n"; they may have needed to replace it with another character.

Answer (score 31):

don't reinvent the wheel, Boost String Algorithms is a header only library and I'm reasonably certain that it works everywhere. If you think the accepted answer code is better because its been provided and you don't need to look in docs, here.

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string str1 = "\r\nsomksdfkmsdf\r\nslkdmsldkslfdkm\r\n";
    boost::replace_all(str1, "\r\n", "Jane");
    std::cout<<str1;
}
```

Comment: or just use standard library functions to avoid the boost dependency: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488775/c-remove-new-line-from-multiline-string

Answer (score 5):

See [Boost String Algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id3677520) library.

Answer (score 3):

First use find() to look for "\r\n", then use replace() to put something else there.
Have a look at the reference, it has some examples:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find.html

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace.html

Comment: Here's an answer that contains a code example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3418285/1279291