# "New Line" connected to value when reading in a CSV?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, csv

I am currently trying to read in a CSV file to place it into an array, but when I execute the code, the program seems to read over the endline to the next comma which messes up my output.  Here is the code:

```
while (!inFile.eof()) {
        string line = "";
        while (count_1 <= numValuesPerLine) {
            getline(inFile, readFromFile, ',');
            line.append(readFromFile);
            count_1++;
        }
        cout << line << endl;
        count_1 = 0;
    }
```

'line' ends up having the value:

```
12345678910111213141516171819202122232425\n1
```

which when I print it, places that newline next to '25' and messes up the output.

(numValuesPerLine = 25 and count_1 is initialized outside of the loop)

I looked around for a similar answer but I could not find anything exactly like what I am trying to do, any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You should note that [`while (!inFile.eof())`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) is the wrong approach.

Comment: What do you suggest @πάνταῥεῖ?

Comment: Can't you just remove new line from your readFromFile string? Something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488775/c-remove-new-line-from-multiline-string

Comment: `while(getline(inFile, readFromFile, ','))` should be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you changed the delimiter from `\n` to `,` so of course the newline is kept as part of the input

Comment: well...I did not think to do that, I thought you had to separate it by comma.  I feel quite foolish now.  Will mark as answered as soon as I can.