# How to pass in a const char* as an argument to an LPCSTR parameter?

Tags: c++, serial-communication, playsound

I'd like to use this function to call the the PlaySoundA function, but the sound file I am trying to play does not open.

```
void AudioClass::playAudio(const char* incomingData, const char* filePath)
{

    char buffer[100]; // <- danger, only storage for 100 characters.
    strncpy_s(buffer, filePath, sizeof(buffer));
    strncat_s(buffer, incomingData, sizeof(buffer));

    PlaySoundA(buffer, NULL, SND_FILENAME);
}
```

As I found out, if the argument for the LPCSTR pszSound parameter of PlaySoundA() is given as a string (e.g. "C:/Users/User/Documents/sound.wav"), i.e. the full path of the file is given, the sound will play.

I would like to combine the incomingData parameter (file name) and the filePath parameter, for which I used a buffer.

If the file cannot be found, the default system sound should play (it was a beep in my case), but this is no longer the case; even though SND_NODEFAULT flag was not set, in which case PlaySoundA() would return silently, without playing the default system sound.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v%3Dvs.85)

Is it possible that the argument I am trying to pass in not compatible with LPCSTR pszSound parameter?

While running the debugger, the buffer variable seems to hold the whole path (C:/Users/User/Documents/sound.wav\r\n), but why is there a \r\n prefix at the end?

Definitions:

```
#define MAX_DATA_LENGTH 255

char incomingData[MAX_DATA_LENGTH];

const char* filePath {"C:/Users/User/Desktop/"};

//Arduino SerialPort object
SerialPort *arduino;

//Audio file AudioClass object
AudioClass* audio;
```

playAudio() is called here:

```
void exampleReceiveData(void)
{
    int readResult = arduino->SerialPort::readSerialPort(incomingData, MAX_DATA_LENGTH);

    audio->AudioClass::playAudio(incomingData, filePath);

    Sleep(10000);
}
```

EDIT_1: the length of the real file path I use is shorter than 100 characters.

EDIT_2: I get this warning: String 'buffer' might not be zero-terminated.

Comment: `\r\n` those are special characters, when You write on the keyboard you don't see them
but `\r` is carriage return and `\n` is new line character system adds them automatically use this to clear the input https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488775/c-remove-new-line-from-multiline-string

Comment: There is an `"\r\n"` there because you read it from the serial port, so it must come from the other end.

Comment: The library you are using is too primitive to be useful. As-is, you need to only read *one* byte, loop until you get \r\n.  You can then also get rid of that giant sleep as well.  Best to keep shopping for one that has a Readline() style function.

Comment: @Hans Passant: yes, if the giant sleep stays giant, the sound stops playing after a while. Reducing sleep to a lower amount helps.

Comment: Its just a hack to lower the odds for the bug.  If the arduino happens to send a string several milliseconds before the sleep expires then it still won't work, you still get a partial string.  Do it right and you don't need any sleep at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `\r\n` at the end comes from the serial port: https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println

You can skip the characters when copying:

```
    strncat_s(buffer, incomingData, strnlen(incomingData) - 2);
```

Comment: [Nope](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/communication/serial/println)