# Convert a string's UNIX line endings to DOS line endings

Tags: c++, string, newline

I'd like to convert a string's UNIX line endings to DOS ones, because my program communicates with a server running on a Linux-based operating system. I've tried using std::replace like that:

```
std::string str = readfromserver(); 
std::replace(str.begin(), str.end(), "\n", "\r\n");
```

but I got the following compiler error:

> error C2782: 'void std::replace(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &,const _Ty &)' : template parameter '_Ty' is ambiguous

Could anyone tell me what am I doing wrong or suggest me a different way of line ending conversion?

Comment: a string is a sequence of `char`

Comment: Then how do you call a `std::string`?

Comment: You won't be able to use `std::replace` to do this as it will only allow you to replace single characters by other single characters.

Comment: you can use the replace from this post : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3418285/3510483

Comment: This might work too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/484213/replace-line-breaks-in-a-stl-string

Comment: Turns out that I didn't need the conversion at all. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What are you trying to do, exactly?  Internally, regardless of the system, line endings are `'\n'`.  If you're on a Windows system, they will be converted correctly in `std::ifstream` and `std::ofstream`, you don't have to worry about it (provided you open the files in text mode).  And an `std::ifstream` will read a file written under Unix without problems.  The *only* time you might have to pay attention to this issue is when writing on Windows and reading on Unix; then you will probably find an extra `'\r'` immediately in front of the `'\n'`.  Normally, this is not a problem either, because the `'\r'` count as legal white space, and you want to ignore trailing white space anyway.

Within a C++ program, you should never see the `'\r'`.

Comment: Turns out that I didn't need the conversion at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/484980/1830736), Boost has an excellent string manipulation library.  And because it's Boost, it's pretty much guaranteed to be as fast as possible.

Use `boost::replace_all`:

```
std::string str = readfromserver();
boost::replace_all(str, "\n", "\r\n");
```

And if you need to go the other way (removing `\r`s), you could just use an standard library algorithm such as `remove_if` and a lambda.

Answer (score 0):

I'd replace "\n" with something that does not itself contain the "\n" escape sequence, such as "\x0x0d\0x0a".